# Ubuntu how can I make / receive a version with ubuntu with packages already built in?

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu how can I build / make / receive a version of Ubuntu with packages already built in?

i.e. Ubuntu installer that i can use to install on a computer that comes with openssh-server, git, nodejs, whatever my heart desires.

And the installer doesn't need to connect to internet to receive these packages (they are baked in already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Ubuntu offers this directly on the website.

And there's also this:  [Ubuntu Customization Kit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/uck/) (may be easier to use)